# SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas: how to set the first value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, compatibility

When running my code I get the following message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['detect'][df.index[0]] = df['event'][df.index[0]]
```

What is the correct way of setting the first value of a column equal to the first value of another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to perform the index label selection:

```
In [102]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'detect':np.random.randn(5), 'event':np.arange(5)})
df
Out[102]:
     detect  event
0 -0.815105      0
1 -0.656923      1
2 -1.417722      2
3  0.210070      3
4  0.211728      4
In [103]:

df.ix[0,'detect'] = df.ix[0,'event']
df
Out[103]:
     detect  event
0  0.000000      0
1 -0.656923      1
2 -1.417722      2
3  0.210070      3
4  0.211728      4
```

What you are doing is called [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and may or may not work hence the warning